# Aptana won't start because workspace has change location

Tags: aptana, workspace

I'm on Mac OS X, and I just installed a secondary drive, onto which I placed my user's home directory.
Now, when I launch Aptana/Titanium Studio, it says that specified workspace cannot be created because directory is either invalid or read-only.
What I guess that it's looking after the old file path.

In what file can I change to the new workspace location?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround.
I simply added a symbolic link into my users’ folder:

myusername -> /Volumes/Second/Home/

Voilà!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I tried to change workspace to a read only location and then couldn't restart.

I searched the usual suspects for a pref file but can't find it. I suspect it's stored somewhere deep in the Eclipse framework files.

I solved it by executing

```
./AptanaStudio3 -data ~Home

from

~/Applications/Aptana Studio 3/AptanaStudio3.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

to reset Workspace to ~Home

Hope this helps a future seeker

Comment: Useful for Ubuntu or Linux users. I was wondering how to pass '-data' attribute. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Is Aptana/Titanium Studio closing after the workspace message or you can get to the preference menu?  If so you can change the workspace location by going to

Aptana/Titanium Studio > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces

Then when you next start the application you will be asked for you workspace location and you can browse to the new location.

Comment: No. After the splash screen, the alert shows and when I close it, it shutdown Titanium Studio...

Comment: The question is: is there a pref file where I can tweek the workspace location?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change it using the config.ini file located at /Application/Titanium Studio/configuration/config.ini.

I have not had reason to do this for Titanium, but I have done in the past for Eclipse and as Titanium/Aptana are basically Eclipse spin offs this should work for them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone faced the same problem and the answer didn't work. My problem was trivial. There was no free space on my HD! (only 2MB). If so, free some space and re-launch Aptana.

(I am wondering why the message was that vague. Why not to say "Free some space" and "free" me from wasting my time!)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I ended up here after copying my Aptana Studio 3 data to a new computer, and placing my Workspace in a different location, which gives the same error that the Workspace can't be opened.

If you installed into the default location (on Windows) and want to tell Aptana where you've moved your Workspace, the file where you can set the path is:

```
%HOMEPATH%\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Aptana Studio\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs
```